# Determine if the following is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $M$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix and $H_7 = \{ A \in M \mid A^T = A \}$, where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$.

I understand that the transpose just swaps the rows and colums, but im not sure how to start proving this one.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales somthing like this? A^t = A and B^t = B then (A+B)^t = A^t + B^t = A + B so it is closed under addition

Comment: If you want to show that the $2\times2$ symmetric matrices are a linear subspace of the $2\times2$ matrices you need to show that scalar multiples of $2\times2$ symmetric matrices are symmetric and that sums of $2\times2$ symmetric matrices are symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the properties of the transpose to help us out.

Let $\bf{0}$ denote the $2\times 2$ matrix with zero entries. Then, clearly, $\bf{0}$$^{T}=\bf{0}$. Hence, $\bf{0}$ $\in H_{7}$.

Next, let $k$ be any scalar and $A\in H_{7}$. It follows that $(kA)^{T}=k(A)^{T}=kA$. Thus, $kA\in H_{7}$, so, $H_{7}$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Finally, if $A,B\in H_{7}$, it follows that $(A+B)^{T}=A^{T}+B^{T}=A+B$. Therefore, $A+B\in H_{7}$, and hence, $H_{7}$ is closed under addition.

We have shown that $H_{7}$ is closed under scalar multiplication and addition, and that $H_{7}$ contains $\bf{0}$. Whence, $H_{7}$ is a subspace of the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices.